# Why Monte Carlo integration is not affected by curse of dimensionality?

Tags: numerical-methods, monte-carlo

What is the common sense explanation behind that fact that MC integration is free of "curse of dimensionality" in contrast to deterministic integration rules (e.g. trapezoidal rule)?

Comment: This is because the normalization $1/\sqrt{n}$ of the central limit theorem does not depend on the dimension.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There do exist deterministic integration rules that don't suffer the "curse of dimensionality", see [sparse grid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_grid) for [example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/49835/12490). What you are referring to when you say "deterministic integration rules" is probably the tensor product approach for constructing multi-dimensional integration rules from one dimensional integration rules.

To see what goes wrong, let's look at the tensor product of two linear one dimensional functions. We will get a bilinear function, but this function won't be linear unless the coefficient of the $xy$ term is zero. In general, a $n$-linear function $f: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ will have $2^n$ degrees of freedom whereas a linear function $l: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ just has $n+1$ degrees of freedom. I should add that what I mean by "linear function" here is a polynomial of degree $1$ or $0$. The "correct" meaning of "linear function" would be something like $l(a+b)=l(a)+l(b)$ and $l(\alpha a)=\alpha l(a)$.